# Dictionary Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, fatal-error

I'm using let to prevent unexpected nil's while unwrapping values, but my function still causes a fatal error.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

-

```
class func getDomain() -> String {
    let (dictionary, error) = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount("account")
    if let dictionary = dictionary {
        if let domain = dictionary["domain"] as? String {
            return domain
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: Hi, this has resolved the issue I think!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your code like this:

```
if let dictionary1 = dictionary {
    if let domain = dictionary1["domain"] as? String {
        return domain
    }
}
```